# How would I write this query with Cypher in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How would I write the following query with Cypher? I need to find out who "Mike" endorses, who endorses someone, who endorses someone, who endorses [X], and then return [X].

I think the query could be written like the following, however it takes several hours to execute:

```
MATCH (me {name:"Mike"}) -[:ENDORSES]->(other1)-[:ENDORSES]->(other2)-[:ENDORSES]->(other3) RETURN other3
```

Comment: What is the length of the path you require? I mean you need to reach [X] in exactly 3 `endorses` relationships, or less than 3

Comment: In exactly 3. :)

Comment: Then change the query to `MATCH (me {name:"Mike"}) -[:ENDORSES*3]->(other) RETURN other`. But then also use `Labels` on the `other` node to use indexing